# How to create child table representing smaller intervals from a table representing a larger interval?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the two columns representing an interval:

Table A:

```
-------------------
| id | from | to  |
-------------------
|  1 | 9.0  | 8.6 |
|  2 | 3.0  | 2.0 |
```

Using Table A, I would like to create the Table below:

Table B:

```
---------------------
| id_a | from | to  |
---------------------
|    1 | 9.0  | 8.8 |
|    1 | 8.8  | 8.6 |
|    2 | 3.0  | 2.8 |
|    2 | 2.8  | 2.6 |
|    2 | 2.6  | 2.4 |
|    2 | 2.4  | 2.2 |
|    2 | 2.2  | 2.0 |
```

There seems to be a generate_series function but it only applies to integer and dates. I also tried to create a variant of generate_series using numeric arguments but it does not work as expected.

How do I query Table A so that I can output Table B?

Comment: `generate_series(9.0, 8.6, -0.2)` works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing the solution of @BasilEricRabi:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c7d4879f0511ed203a809de63a419051)

There is no need for two executions of `generate_series` if you put it into the `FROM` list:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    gs,
    gs - 0.2
FROM 
    intervals,
    generate_series("from", "to" + 0.2, -0.2) gs
```

---

**Disclaimer**: The words *from* and *to* are restricted keywords in PostgreSQL. So it is strongly recommended to chose other column names!

Answer (score 0):

Silly me! Thank you @a_horse_with_no_name for the guidance. Just started using postgresql recently. The solution is so trivial.

```sql
SELECT id as id_a,
       generate_series(from, to + 0.2, -0.2) as from,
       generate_series(from - 0.2, to, -0.2) as to
FROM table_a ;
```